# How to replace word with special character from string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I am writing a method that should replace all words which match with ones from the list with '****'.

So far I have code that works fine with strings without special characters but all string with special characters are ignoring.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
public static String maskKeywordData(String data, List<String> keywords) {
  for (String keyword: keywords) {
            String insensitiveWord = "(?i)\\b" + keyword + "\\b";
            data = data.replaceAll(insensitiveWord, StringUtils.repeat("*", keyword.length()));
        }
        return data;
    }
```

E.g. I have a list of keywords ['c.u.n.t', 'a$$', 'bitch'].

Input : "Hello c.u.n.t with a$$ and bitch"

Expected output : "Hello ******* with *** and *****"

Comment: You could replace obscene words with neutral ones in your example. It does not affect the actual results.

Comment: StringUtils is not needed here.  The String class has its own [repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) method.  Just use `"*".repeat(keyword.length())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
public static String maskKeywordData(String data, List<String> keywords) {
    for (String keyword : keywords) {
        String insensitiveWord = "(?i)\\b" + keyword;
        data = data.replaceAll(insensitiveWord, "*".repeat(keyword.length()));
    }
    return data;
}
```

Its only downside is, in the list, for `$` you have to use`\\$` in the word, like `a$$` will be `a\\$\\$` in the list for the above code to run.
Reason is, `\\b` is word boundary which checks for `(^ \w|\w $|\W \w|\w \W)`, due to which the word a$$ is not taken.
Output by the above code:
`Hello ******* with **** and *****`